# Handling multiple Symfony sites depending on the URL path

Tags: apache-2.4, symfony

I have multiple Symfony projects, each of them are stored in custom subdirs inside 
`/srv/http`; these subdirs are not intended to be public URLs. For example:

```
/srv/http/some/dir/sfprojA
/srv/http/some/other/dir/sfprojB
...
```

*Note*: I only have a personnal IP address, without any registered domain, and I'm using Apache 
2.4.

I would like to link each of these projects to a simple URL (one per site), with a transparent rewrite 
for the final user. For example, `http://my_ip/siteA` would link to the `sfprojA` default 
route, `http://my_ip/siteA/css/mystyle.css` would link to the given stylesheet, etc...

For the moment, the only way I manage to handle multiple Symfony sites is to use the Apache
virtual hosts feature:

```
Listen 10000
Listen 10001 https

<Location /siteA>
    Redirect http://my_ip:10000
</Location>

<VirtualHost *:10000>
    DocumentRoot /srv/http/some/dir/sfprojA/web

    <Directory /srv/http/some/dir/sfprojA/web>
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:10001>
    DocumentRoot /srv/http/some/dir/sfprojA/web

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/etc/httpd/conf/ssl/mycert.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/httpd/conf/ssl/mycert.key"

    <Directory /srv/http/some/dir/sfprojA/web>
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

It's working (assuming that the project was configured to handle https with port 10001), but there are several big problems:

- Because `/siteA` is a redirection, the final user sees URLs like 
  `http://my_ip:10000/...` instead of `http://my_ip/siteA/...`
- It constrains me to open one port (or two ports with https) for EACH project I want to make 
  public. And the routing configuration is not flexible at all, because I have to go each 
  time to the web portal of my ISP in order to change anything.

How can I remove these problems by changing the Apache configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Forgot all this vhost stuff. All you really need to do is to set [`Alias`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias)es in your main vhost:

```
Alias  "/siteA" "/srv/http/some/dir/sfprojA" 
Alias  "/siteB" "/srv/http/some/other/dir/sfprojB"
```

See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work, because Symfony routes need to be passed through `web/app.php`. I will edit my question later